# Host C# web API in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, api-design

I am just finishing up C# web API and am wondering on the best way to deploy it on AWS. I am aware I could boot up a VM in the cloud and host it in IIS , is this the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spinning up one or more Ec2 instances is one way, and there is nothing wrong with that approach.

Two other options:

1. employ elastic beanstalk to automate the deployment for you -
   but it still ends up running on EC2 instances.
2. convert your WebAPI to API Gateway & C#/Lambda functions instead and
   run it 'serverless'. Depending on the requirements of your
   application this may or may not be a viable option for you.